# How to remove libexec/qt4 and libexec/qt5 with Macports packages manager?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt4, macports

I am trying to remove all Macports packages concerning `QT` on MacOS 11.2 Big Sur (I switch to `brew` packages manager).

A simple question:

Which Macport packages allow to remove `/opt/local/libexec/qt4/` and `/opt/local/libexec/qt5/` directories ?

Comment: As per my previous advice, please refrain from adding chatty remarks to your questions. This is a Q&A site, not a forum.

Comment: General advice: _Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Craig's answer explains how to uninstall all ports, but if you only want to uninstall specific ports that had installed certain files, but you don't know which port installed them, `port provides` answers that question. It doesn't operate on directories, so you have to pick a file, but for example:

```
$ port provides /opt/local/libexec/qt5/bin/moc
/opt/local/libexec/qt5/bin/moc is provided by: qt5-qtbase
```

Now we know that we can get rid of that file by running:

```
$ sudo port uninstall qt5-qtbase
```

If any further items remain in /opt/local/libexec/qt5 that we want to get rid of, we can run `port provides` on another file and repeat the process.

Answer (score 1):

MacPorts recommends to select one package manager and install only from the one.  Having more than one active can lead to very difficult-to-debug problems.

Therefore if you wish to continue with Homebrew, remove all installed MacPorts ports with:

```
sudo port uninstall installed
```

Comment: Full MacPorts uninstallation instructions are at https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html